# Best Practices Concerning Method Locking

Tags: c#, .net, locking, synchronized

I have a method whom access myst be synchronized allowing only one thread at once to go though it. Here is my current implementation:

```
private Boolean m_NoNeedToProceed;
private Object m_SynchronizationObject = new Object();

public void MyMethod()
{
    lock (m_SynchronizationObject)
    {
        if (m_NoNeedToProceed)
            return;
```

Now I was thinking about changing it a little bit like so:

```
private Boolean m_NoNeedToProceed;
private Object m_SynchronizationObject = new Object();

public void MyMethod()
{
    if (m_NoNeedToProceed)
        return;

    lock (m_SynchronizationObject)
    {
```

Shouldn't it be better to do a quick return before locking it so that calling threads can proceed without waiting for the previous one to complete the method call?

Comment: Where can `m_NoNeedToProceed` be set?

Comment: In other methods. For example when users click a button or whatever else. It's just a condition that can sometimes be set in order to avoid that method to run.

Comment: @Zarathos It is safe to assume to access to  `bool, char, byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float, reference type` is atomic., So reading/writing a bool is safe.

Comment: @I4V Yes, but but there is no guarantee they will be "fresh" on a multi-core CPU. You need  a memory barrier for that (using a lock or volatile or Thread.MemoryBarrier()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't it be better to do a quick return before locking it...

No. A lock is is not just a mutual-exclusion mechanism, it's also a **memory barrier<sup>1</sup>**. Without a lock, you could introduce a data race if any of the concurrent threads tries to modify the variable<sup>2</sup>.

BTW, locks have a good performance when there is no contention, so you wouldn't be gaining much performance anyway. As always, refrain from making assumptions about performance, especially this "close to the metal". If in doubt, measure!

> ...so that calling threads can proceed without waiting for the previous one to complete the method call?

This just means you are holding the lock for longer than necessary. Release the lock as soon as the shared memory no longer needs protection (which might be sooner than the method exit), and you won't need to try to artificially circumvent it.

---

*<sup>1</sup> I.e. triggers a cache coherency mechanism so all CPU cores see the "same" memory.*

*<sup>2</sup> For example, one thread writes to the variable, but that change lingers in one core's write buffer for some time, so other threads on other cores don't see it immediately.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as `m_NoNeedToProceed` doesn't have any race conditions associated with it.

If the method takes a long time to run, and some threads do not need to actually access the critical sections of the method. Then it would be best to let them return early without getting the lock.

Comment: As long as `m_NoNeedToProceed` is discretly set, outside of the critical section of the method and independent of other threads for example, it should be fine.  I just want to make sure a thread inside `MyMethod` wouldn't be toggling this bool causing another thread to exit early when it really shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's better to that before you lock.

Make `m_NoNeedToProceed` **[volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

Just a disclaimer: **volatile** doesn't make it thread safe. It just causes a barrier to check if the value has changed in another processor.

Comment: The very name of the thing itself should conjure up concern.